# Parents that do not allow outlets for stress

Tags: violence

What if a kid wanted to dedicate a portion of a room of an apartment to installing Judo-like padding, and perhaps even boxing bags, to go to and take out the stress of when parents shouted at them? What if when they did this parents shouted at them even more.

I hate my parents. They stress me out, and do not accept my need to have a stress relief space within the house, nor do they accept pouncing or kicking, but then again, if I were not blind they could probably not accept reading either.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems you are very angry at your parents. What usually happens child insists to do something and tell his parents about the demand. He does not tries to convince parents in an constructive way. Rather he tries to insist. On the other hand some parents carry a habit of rejecting child's demand as soon as hearing. Both is not a good practice.

Your parents has a long age gaps with you and they like to think in their own ways. Try to convince them in a constructive way, you can show them youtube video or slide show or documentary which supports or emphasis on your demand and then try to tell them in a decent voice. Often parents reject without thinking the good sides of it. They always thought the bad sides or concentrate on risk zone only. Try to place yourself on their position and think and find out why they not allowing you. If you can figure out, try to fix those and approach again in a better way.

***Anger is the root cause of all problems AND
Softness/love/patience is the key of success***

*Note: I am not telling that you approached in an indecent way. I am telling the average case of young child :P*

Comment: I am favoriteing your post. Wise words.

Comment: However, how would I convince my parents that sometimes I need to shout, I need to get angry, and I don't want to shout at anyone, I just want to shout, maybe even punch a padded wall, and not because I want to seem crazy but for a reason: following the let out a nice period of calm follows that allows me to get just about as much attention as I need to study or accomplish a task at hand at a chair and desk. Now, what YouTube video would illustrate the benefits of exercising a short burst of anger with done shooting and optionally some padded surface pouncing? Thanks.

Comment: Here are some helpful links for you: 

[link 1](http://www.criticalcactus.com/benefits-punching-bag-at-home-or-office/)

[link 2](http://www.cranberrycounseling.com/punching.html)

[link 3](http://www.moneycrashers.com/health-benefits-boxing-workouts/)

[link 4](http://healthyliving.azcentral.com/benefits-hitting-punching-bag-sand-bag-7012.html)

Comment: Thank you, Nazmul, for your links on the benefits of having a punching bag at hone. What about links related to the benefits of shooting and yelling at hone or in private? Thanks.